# how to solve maximization problem in octave

Tags: octave

Hello everyone i have the following assignment:
[screen assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMAdw.png)

And the following code:

```
c = [-12; -15; -20; -10];  % Coefficients of the objective function to be maximized

A = [
    1, 1/2, 3, 7;   % Oil type 1
    4, 2, 5, 6;     % Oil type 2
    8, 1/3, 4, 1    % Oil type 3
];

b = [1000; 1500; 2000];  % RHS values of the processing time constraints

lb = [50; 0; 0; 0];      % Lower bounds on the variables
ub = [ 50; 250; 350; 10 ]; % Upper bounds on the variables

ctype = "UUU";      % Constraints are all <=
vartype = "CCCC";     % Variables are continuous

s = -1;              % Objective sense: -1 for maximization

param.msglev = 1;    % Output option: 1 -> Error and warning messages only
param.itlim = 100;   % Iteration limit

[xmax, fmax, status, extra] = glpk(c, A, b, lb, ub, ctype, vartype, s, param);

xmax  % Optimal solution vector [x1, x2, x3, x4]
fmax  % Optimal objective value (total profit per week)
status  % Status of the solver
```

And the following output:

```
   50
    0
    0
    0

fmax = -600
status = 0
```

Why I get a negative value?
If something is not clear let me know

Comment: i think this is an  Assignment ?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: Your coefficients `c` are all negative and the elements of your solution vector `xmax` are all positive. So why are you surprised that the product `c' * xmax` is negative?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

- The negative value in the code s = -1 is used to indicate that the
  objective function should be maximized . In this case, the objective
  coefficients c are multiplied by -1 to convert the maximization
  problem into a minimization problem.
- If you want to maximize the objective function, you can change the
  code s = -1 to s = 1. This will set the objective sense to 1 for
  maximization.

Comment: This answer is not correct. The fact that maximization is turned into a linimization is some internal stuff to the library routine, which has no reason to affect the output values.

Answer (score 1):

The coefficients of your objective function are all negative, and the elements of your solution vector are all positive: consequently the objective function is negative.

There are many issues in you code:

- why are you using negative coefficients?
- your assignment describes 4 contraints (the max number of hours available in the 4 units) but you have only 3
- your assignment describes 3 unknown variables (the quantities of 3 different oils) but you 4 unknown variables (and you are inventing a coefficient and lower/upper bounds for the 4th one).

Here is a more correct code:

```
c = [12; 15; 20];  % Coefficients of the objective function to be maximized

A = [
    1, 1/2, 3, 7;   % Oil type 1
    4, 2, 5, 6;     % Oil type 2
    8, 1/3, 4, 1    % Oil type 3
];
A = A';   % transposition, as A is supposed to be a 4x3 matrix

b = [1000; 1500; 2000; 1400];  % RHS values of the processing time constraints

lb = [50; 0; 0];       % Lower bounds on the variables
ub = [ 250; 350; 10 ]; % Upper bounds on the variables

ctype = "UUUU";      % Constraints are all <=
vartype = "CCC";     % Variables are continuous

s = -1;              % Objective sense: -1 for maximization

param.msglev = 1;    % Output option: 1 -> Error and warning messages only
param.itlim = 100;   % Iteration limit

[xmax, fmax, status, extra] = glpk(c, A, b, lb, ub, ctype, vartype, s, param);

xmax  % Optimal solution vector [x1, x2, x3, x4]
fmax  % Optimal objective value (total profit per week)
status  % Status of the solver
```

Ouput:

```
xmax =

    50.000
   173.333
    10.000

fmax = 3400
status = 0
```